# Android: Record Audio - Get result after stopping the Recording

Tags: android, mediastore

I'm developing the Audio Capture in Android. I have referred

[How to Make custome record view Meter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442975/how-to-make-custome-record-view-meter)

Here i can get the result after coming out of the media. But i want the result after stopping the record. Is there any option???

My Code:

```
    MediaRecorder recorder;
    public static int RECORD_REOUEST = 0;


@Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Intent intt = new Intent(Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
      startActivityForResult(intt, RECORD_REOUEST);
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{   
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == RECORD_REOUEST) 
     {
        Uri recordedAudioPath = data.getData();         
     }
}
```

**Note: Issue only with Device.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the android.media.MediaRecorder to accomplish this by having a start() and stop() method

```
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();

public void start() {
  recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
  recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
  recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
  recorder.setOutputFile(path);
  recorder.prepare();
  recorder.start();
}
  public void stop() {
  recorder.stop();
  recorder.release();
}
```

Look at this similar post [Stackoverflow Record Audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962172/how-do-i-record-audio-using-android-1-5) for a full example. It saves the recording to the external storage you can reach when you stop the recording.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to get the result inside the OnActivityResult method.

Comment: Hmm okay. When you press "Done" the OnActivityResult is fired and the path is saved in the Uri recordedAudioPath. What do you want to accomplish? you have the correct path something like: "content://media/external/audio/media/..." and can use the path when you return from the Intent("android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND");

Comment: Please check my edited code, After recording there is no option like "Done".

Comment: requestCode return 0 for me. I tested on 4.0.3 and 2.1. Which version are you running on? The "done" button I'm talking about is from your link example that gives the Record_Sound intent. Don't you get a view similar to this after recording a message: http://spacetech.dk/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/MessageRecorded-576x1024.png

Comment: Not getting like in this image. I'm checking with Android device.

Comment: If I'm pressing back button, then getting Result_OK as -1.

Comment: Just tried on 1.6 and the button have difference names but do the same. "Discard" and "Use this recording". Are you running in a emulator or on a device? If you're running an emulator did you set a size on the SD on e.g. 100MiB. Could be because it can't save the recorded audio, hence you don't get a result back.

Comment: I'm checking with the Android mobile. Please check with the mobile.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11217/discussion-between-priebe-and-ponmalar)